# Web-part error: (401) Unauthorized

Tags: sharepoint, web-parts

I have a little program that queries a web service, transforms the results using XSLT and displays them in a jQuery control. When I move the code into a web part it and deploy it, however I'm getting the following error:

```
The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.
```

This is the code that's loading my XSLT file, which is where I suspect the problem is:

```
XPathDocument xPathDoc;
XsltArgumentList args;

protected override void OnPreRender(EventArgs e)
{
  xPathDoc = QueryRunner.GetQueryResults();
  args = QueryRunner.GetColumnsToShow();
}

public static XPathDocument GetQueryResults()
{
  OpacAccess.OpacAccess proxy = new OpacAccess.OpacAccess();

  string result = string.Empty;

  try
  {
     result = proxy.query("CompanyName", "username", "password", 
         ReadingList=\"London\"", 1000);
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
  }

  // Store the xml of the result
  XPathDocument xPathDoc = new XPathDocument(new StringReader(result));

  return xPathDoc;
}   

protected override void RenderContents(HtmlTextWriter output)
{
  XslTransform xslt = new XslTransform();

  // Load the xslt file and perform the transformation
  xslt.Load("http://rginfonet/Style%20Library/XSL%20Style%20Sheets/Liberty.xslt");
  xslt.Transform(xPathDoc, args, output, null);
  output.Flush();
}
```

Here's my stack trace if it's at all helpful to anyone:

[WebException: The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.] System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse() +5375213 System.Xml.XmlDownloadManager.GetNonFileStream(Uri uri, ICredentials credentials) +69 System.Xml.XmlDownloadManager.GetStream(Uri uri, ICredentials credentials) +3929371 System.Xml.XmlUrlResolver.GetEntity(Uri absoluteUri, String role, Type ofObjectToReturn) +54 System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.OpenUrlDelegate(Object xmlResolver) +74 System.Threading.CompressedStack.runTryCode(Object userData) +70 System.Runtime.CompilerServices.RuntimeHelpers.ExecuteCodeWithGuaranteedCleanup(TryCode code, CleanupCode backoutCode, Object userData) +0 System.Threading.CompressedStack.Run(CompressedStack compressedStack, ContextCallback callback, Object state) +108 System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.OpenUrl() +186 System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Read() +208 System.Xml.XPath.XPathDocument.LoadFromReader(XmlReader reader, XmlSpace space) +217 System.Xml.XPath.XPathDocument..ctor(XmlReader reader, XmlSpace space) +20 System.Xml.Xsl.XsltOld.Compiler.LoadDocument(XmlTextReaderImpl reader) +85 System.Xml.Xsl.XslTransform.Load(String url, XmlResolver resolver) +100 System.Xml.Xsl.XslTransform.Load(String url) +25 LibertyControl.ResultsGrid.RenderContents(HtmlTextWriter output) +74 System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebControl.Render(HtmlTextWriter writer) +32 System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControlInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter) +27 System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter) +99 System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter writer) +25 System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildrenInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ICollection children) +134 System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildren(HtmlTextWriter writer) +19 System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebControl.RenderContents(HtmlTextWriter writer) +10 System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebControl.Render(HtmlTextWriter writer) +32 System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControlInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter) +27 System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter) +99 System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter writer) +25 Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.SPChrome.RenderPartContents(HtmlTextWriter output, WebPart part) +66

[WebPartException: The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.] Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.SPChrome.RenderPartContents(HtmlTextWriter output, WebPart part) +140 Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.SPChrome.RenderWebPart(HtmlTextWriter output, WebPart part) +63 Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.WebPartZone.RenderZoneCell(HtmlTextWriter output, Boolean bMoreParts, WebPart part) +144 Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.WebPartZone.RenderWebParts(HtmlTextWriter output, ArrayList webParts) +495 Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.WebPartZone.Render(HtmlTextWriter output) +902 System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControlInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter) +27 System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter) +99 System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter writer) +25 System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildrenInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ICollection children) +134 System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildren(HtmlTextWriter writer) +19 System.Web.UI.Control.Render(HtmlTextWriter writer) +10 System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControlInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter) +27 System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter) +99 System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter writer) +25 System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildrenInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ICollection children) +134 System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildren(HtmlTextWriter writer) +19 System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlContainerControl.Render(HtmlTextWriter writer) +32 System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControlInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter) +27 System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter) +99 System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter writer) +25 System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildrenInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ICollection children) +134 System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildren(HtmlTextWriter writer) +19 System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlForm.RenderChildren(HtmlTextWriter writer) +163 System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlContainerControl.Render(HtmlTextWriter writer) +32 System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlForm.Render(HtmlTextWriter output) +51 System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControlInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter) +27 System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter) +99 System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlForm.RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter writer) +40 System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildrenInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ICollection children) +134 System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildren(HtmlTextWriter writer) +19 System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlContainerControl.Render(HtmlTextWriter writer) +32 System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControlInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter) +27 System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter) +99 System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter writer) +25 System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildrenInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ICollection children) +134 System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildren(HtmlTextWriter writer) +19 System.Web.UI.Control.Render(HtmlTextWriter writer) +10 System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControlInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter) +27 System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter) +99 System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter writer) +25 System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildrenInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ICollection children) +134 System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildren(HtmlTextWriter writer) +19 System.Web.UI.Page.Render(HtmlTextWriter writer) +29 System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControlInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter) +27 System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter) +99 System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter writer) +25 System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +1266

Please let me know if you can lend some insight to what's causing this. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The account responsible for rendering the webpart does not have access to the document library where you have the xslt located.

There are a few ways to get around this,

1. Give permissions to the system account to access that library
2. Use impersonation
3. If the xslt won't change that much then include it as a resource of the webpart

Comment: Thanks!  It sounds like the easiest way would be to include it as a resource.  Originally, the program was reaching out to a directory on my hard drive for the XSLT file, but this won't work moving forward.  Can you point me to a good resource where it's explained how to include a resource in a webpart in Sharepoint 2007?

Comment: You can include the XSLT as an embedded resource inside the assembly.

Answer (score 0):

If you deployed your webpart in the bin folder ,might be that folder won't have permissions and not able to show you the webpart.Add sufficient permissions.